# Upload an image file using the request object

Tags: javascript, file-upload, request, firefox-addon-sdk

In the Firefox extension I am currently developing, I've been trying for days now to upload an image file to a server using the `request` module of the Firefox Add-on SDK.
I managed to upload a text file but I cannot upload any other kind of files.
My final goal is to upload a screenshot so I really need to be able to upload an image.
Here is my current code:

```js
params= file.read("C:\\FullPath\h3nf5v2c.png", "b");

//multipart form data
boundary = "---------------------------132611019532525";
var snapShotUpload = Request({
    url : "https://myurl.com",
        headers : {
        "Referer" : "https://myurl.com",
    "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary,
    },
    content :  "--" + boundary + "\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='Upload_FileName'; filename='h3nf5v2c.png'\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" + params + "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n",                          
    onComplete: function(response) {
        console.log(response.text);
    }                        
});
console.log("request built");
snapShotUpload.post();
```

The uploaded image is corrupted and I can't read it.

So my question is:
How do I post an image using the `request` module of the Firefox Add-on SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Wladimir,

I didn't actually modify the Request module but simply used an XMLHttpRequest instead.
Here is the code I used if anybody is interested:

```
function sendImage(file){
        fName = "h3nf5v2c.png";

    // prepare the MIME POST data
    var boundaryString = '---------------------------132611019532525';
    var boundary = '--' + boundaryString;
    var requestbody = boundary + '\r\n'
            + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload_FileName"; filename="'
            + fName + '"' + '\r\n'
            + 'Content-Type: image/png' + '\r\n'
            + '\r\n'
            + file.read()
            + '\r\n'
            + boundary + '--\r\n';

    // Send
    var http_request = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
            .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);

    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200) {
            console.log(http_request.responseText);
        }
    };

    http_request.open('POST', 'http://myUrl.com', true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Referer", "http://myUrl.com");                  
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString);
    //http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", requestbody.length);
    http_request.sendAsBinary(requestbody);    

}
```

The file parameter of the function is a file object from the file module.

The sendAsBinary function at the end is very important because I'm working client side only and I had to simulate an insert via a form.
If you have access to the server side, sending a base64 encoded version of the image and decoding it server-side is probably simpler.

Comment: This won't work, file objects with binary content don't have a default .toString() ifier.

Comment: Ok, my file parameter is actually a file.read(). I edited my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is: you cannot. The `request` module is mainly meant to transmit url-encoded data so anything that isn't a string is assumed to be an object containing key-value pairs that need to be encoded. So sending a string is your only option if you need to send multipart content yet `XMLHttpRequest` will always encode strings as UTF-8 which will produce rather undesirable results when you are trying to send raw binary data (such as an image data).

It would be much easier to [use a `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) but even if you create one - the `request` module won't pass it to `XMLHttpRequest`. There is no simple solution short of modifying the `request` module (file `packages/addon-kit/lib/request.js` of the Add-on SDK). Find this line:

```js
let data = stringify(content);
```

Changing it into the following code should work:

```js
let {Ci} = require("chrome");
let data = content;
if (!(content instanceof Ci.nsIDOMFormData))
  data = stringify(content);
```

This makes sure that `FormData` objects aren't changed.

Note that you might not have `FormData` and `File` defined in your `main.js`. If that's the case "stealing" them from any JavaScript module should work:

```js
let {Cu} = require("chrome");
var {FormData, File} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way to post an image on your server. You can use the base64 encoding.
I never test it but I found [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) on the web which explains how to convert the image. I hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes, I had already thought of that, but I didn't work, my server will only accept binary files. But I'm going to try Mr Palant 's technique. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What can simplify your life is using FormData and XMLHttpRequests together as in this example.

```
function uploadFiles(url, files) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {
        formData.append(file.name, file);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

    xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data
}

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    uploadFiles('/server', this.files);
}, false);
```

source: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/